# Complex integration of $\log(z)$ over a closed counter-clockwise curve containing the origin only once

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

What's the integral of $\log(z)$ in $C$, where $C$ is a closed curve enclosing the origin only once (counter-clockwise)?

I tried to use the circle with radius $r$, $\{z=re^{\theta i} : \theta \in (0,2\pi) \}$, but then I obtain the result $2 \pi r i$, and I think that the result should not depend on the radius.

Comment: In the cut plane, the antiderivative of $\log(z)$ is $z\log(z)-z$.  Now, what happens at the endpoints of the contour on each side of the branch cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> You can choose any curve that encloses the origin. In particular,
>   $\ds{\braces{z \mid z = \expo{\theta\,\ic} \mid \theta \in \pars{0,2\pi}}}$ which indeed is evaluated as a limiting case which 'takes care' of the, for example, $\ds{\ln}$-*Principal Branch*.

Namely,
\begin{align}
&\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\braces{%
-\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\bracks{\ln\pars{-x} + \pi\ic}\dd x -
\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}\bracks{\ln\pars{\epsilon} + \theta\,\ic}\epsilon\expo{\theta\,\ic}\ic\,\dd\theta
-\int_{-\epsilon}^{-1}\bracks{\ln\pars{-x} - \pi\ic}\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &
-\int_{0}^{1}\pi\ic\,\dd x + \int_{0}^{1}\pars{-\pi\ic}\dd x =
\bbx{-2\pi\ic}
\end{align}